# Guy is reincarnated into another world as a teenage member of a sect that wants to kill him

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

A guy is reincarnated into another world where he is a teenager of a sect and his master is the sect leader.

The main character starts off weak and untalented. His sect wants to kill him but the sect leader fights for his defense. The sect leader is killed by his brothers in the sect and the kid starts to hunt his killers down and kill them.

My memory is hazy but the main character travels with this ice queen who is over-powered. It's a martial arts manwha.

Comment: Given you mention sects, is this a cultivation story? Honestly, what you've described is essentially an entire genre. Does the "ice queen" have ice powers or just an icy personality? What ethnicity are the characters? Do you remember the protagonist's hair color or hairstyle?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters or locations?

Comment: This could be "God of Martial Arts" (main character is named Lin Feng), but as others have mentioned, it is hard to narrow down solely based on these common tropes.